# Why no call_at_threadsafe and call_later_threadsafe?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm using Python 3.5.2 in Windows 32bits and aware that asyncio call_at is not threadsafe, hence following code won't print 'bomb' unless I uncomment the line  `loop._write_to_self()`.

```
import asyncio
import threading


def bomb(loop):
    loop.call_later(1, print, 'bomb')
    print('submitted')
    # loop._write_to_self()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    threading.Timer(2, bomb, args=(loop,)).start()
    loop.run_forever()
```

However I couldn't find a piece of information about why `call_at_threadsafe` and `call_later_threadsafe` is implemented. Is the reason ever exists?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply use [`loop.call_soon_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.call_soon_threadsafe) to schedule `loop.call_later`:

```
loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.call_later, 1, print, 'bomb')
```

Comment: but this slowed down execution speed isn't it? Since it have to submit call_later to the loop, then call_later submit print ......

Comment: @SpringMaple This sounds like premature optimization. As long as your program is correctly written (e.g. no blocking calls), the callback will effectively be called "soon" enough. However, I think the `_write_to_self` alternative is acceptable.

Comment: At first I was thinking that run_coroutine_threadsafe you contributed is the same concept as loop.call_later_threadsafe (because we could use `loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.create_task(coro))`) until I realize that it returns an future object for a use case (wait for async loop to execute and return result, from another thread) which I thought the use case was impossible to achieve previously. Thanks again, you helped me to learn new thing in 2 questions in a roll!

Comment: @Vincent you saved my life... without call_soon_threadsafe only call_later doesn't work at all...